# How do I use queues to send data?

Tags: c#

If I was to, from various sources, put data in a queue, and whenever it has anything to send, it sends it and then waits for a time. So, for example, the queue is empty, I send in 2 things to send, it sends the first thing instantly and then waits for a bit before sending the next. How would I do this?

Comment: you could use a foreach loop and a timer (not necessarily the best solution)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should have a producer/consumer queue, with a single consumer which delays after consuming. (The consumer would be on a different thread to the producers, of course.)

From .NET 4 onwards, [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) is the fundamental building block of producer/consumer queues. You should also look at [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) though - it may have a simple way of doing this out of the box. (DataFlow is a library specifically aimed at producer/consumer scenarios.)

Comment: @Cool12309: Which, `BlockingCollection<T>`? I've already given you an outline. That, combined with a bit of research on MSDN, should be enough to implement it. If you want more information, you'll have to ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @Jon_Skeet How do I know when something has been added to the queue?